# Derivative of component wise power of a vector

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis, matrix-calculus

let $v = [v_1,v_2,...,v_n]^T$. Define the component wise a-th power of $v^a$ be $[v_1^a,v_2^a,...,v_n^a]^T$. What is $\frac{dv^a}{dv}$ and how to arrive at it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matrix multiplication of *diagonal* matrices can replace component-wise multiplication of vectors.

In particular,
if $\def\o{{\tt1}}\o$ is the all-ones vector
and $\def\Diag{\operatorname{Diag}} V=\Diag(v)\:$ then
$$\eqalign{
v^{(n)} &= V^n\,\o \\
dv^{(n)} &= dV^{n}\:\o = nV^{n-1}\:dV\,\o  = nV^{n-1}\:dv \\
\frac{\partial v^{(n)}}{\partial v} &= nV^{n-1} \\
}$$
As a check, note that setting $n=\tt1$ recovers the well-known result
$$\frac{\partial v}{\partial v} = I$$

### Update

The `Diag()` function cannot be represented using only matrix products, but if you allow elementwise/[Hadamard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices)) products then
$$\Diag(v) \;=\; I\odot\left(v\o^T\right)
 \;=\; I\odot\left(\o v^T\right)$$
Another possibility is to extend the [Kronecker delta symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta) to three indices
$$\def\d{\vec\delta} \d_{ijk} = \begin{cases}
\o\qquad {\rm if}\;\;i=j=k \\
0\qquad {\rm otherwise} \\
\end{cases}$$
Then you can use a matrix product (aka *dot product*) to write
$$\Diag(v) \;=\; \d\cdot v \;=\; v\cdot\d$$

Comment: is it possible to express $V$ in terms of something linear in $v$? Like for $\frac{d x^{T}x}{dx}=2x$ the derivative is linear in $x$.

Comment: @Sam Given vector $(a)$ and its diagonal matrix $(A)$ note that
$$a+\lambda v \quad\implies\quad A+\lambda V$$
so diagonalization is a perfectly linear operation.  
However, even in the **scalar** case $\alpha^n$ nor its derivative $n\alpha^{n-1}$ are linear functions of $\alpha$. Things are no different in the case of vectors (or matrices).

Comment: sorry my bad what I meant was if it is possible to express the $Diag(v)$ operator as some function of $v$, be it matrix multiplication of $v$ with some other matrices, or itself (i.e. exponentiation)

Comment: @Sam $\;$I've updated the answer.$\;$

Comment: thanks a lot for your input. appreciate it